# How can i have view upper side if i am writing code in down side

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This is my HTML and CSS. I want a result like the image posted below. I have the number 1 on the top, and 2 on the bottom according to my code, but without changing the HTML, I want to have the result show 2 on the top and 1 on the bottom. I am trying to use CSS grid of bootstrap.

```
<style>
    .grid-container {
      grid-template-columns: footer header;
      grid-gap: 10px;
      background-color: #2196F3;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .item1 { grid-area: footer; }
    .item2 { grid-area: header; }
    
.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>   

 <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="item1">1</div>
      <div class="item2">2</div>
 </div>
```

result -:

[image: this is the result showing me]

but i want the result

[image: require this result]

HTML should not be changed. I want change in only CSS.

Comment: I not the expert of grid.
But please check the below, It might help you out. 
https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/ZpzrxV

Comment: good try. But it is showing like grid. but i want to get result like table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `flex-wrap:wrap-reverse`.

```css
.grid-container {
  grid-template-columns: footer header;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  display: flex;
  width:calc(100% - 20px);
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: header;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove your `grid-container` class and add `flex-row d-flex` this two bootstrap class.
Hope this will solve your problem.

```css
<style>
    .grid-container {
      grid-template-columns: footer header;
      grid-gap: 10px;
      background-color: #2196F3;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
.item1, .item2 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.block{
 background-color: #2196F3;
      padding: 10px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="flex-row d-flex block">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item1">2</div>
</div>
```